# Are Status Update Notifications returning iOS 6 or iOS 7 style receipts?

Tags: ios, sandbox, auto-renewable

I've been consuming the new Apple Status Update Notifications in Sandbox for auto-renewable subscriptions. The latest_receipt_info field, however, doesn't appear to match iOS 7 style receipts (e.g. no in_app field).

Is this unique to only Sandbox or is this how I should expect the notifications to work in Product?

Example receipt received from Status Update Notification after verifying with Apple:

```
{
  "auto_renew_status": 0,
  "latest_expired_receipt_info": {
    "original_purchase_date_pst": "2018-01-19 16:03:00 America/Los_Angeles",
    "unique_identifier": "9d89432f1fae59f25c05d44553fe40438a865b9f",
    "original_transaction_id": "1000000368245564",
    "expires_date": "1517368991000",
    "transaction_id": "1000000371718901",
    "quantity": "1",
    "product_id": "abc",
    "bvrs": "721180.450460032",
    "bid": "ab.bc",
    "unique_vendor_identifier": "9982B084-BE66-4622-ACCB-6C5B3D9C4CD4",
    "web_order_line_item_id": "1000000037662245",
    "original_purchase_date_ms": "1516406580000",
    "expires_date_formatted": "2018-01-31 03:23:11 Etc/GMT",
    "purchase_date": "2018-01-31 02:53:11 Etc/GMT",
    "is_in_intro_offer_period": "false",
    "purchase_date_ms": "1517367191000",
    "expires_date_formatted_pst": "2018-01-30 19:23:11 America/Los_Angeles",
    "is_trial_period": "false",
    "purchase_date_pst": "2018-01-30 18:53:11 America/Los_Angeles",
    "original_purchase_date": "2018-01-20 00:03:00 Etc/GMT",
    "item_id": "1326212778"
  },
  "status": 21006,
  "auto_renew_product_id": "abc",
  "receipt": {
    "original_purchase_date_pst": "2018-01-19 16:03:00 America/Los_Angeles",
    "unique_identifier": "9d89432f1fae59f25c05d44553fe40438a865b9f",
    "original_transaction_id": "1000000368245564",
    "expires_date": "1517359990000",
    "transaction_id": "1000000371686472",
    "quantity": "1",
    "product_id": "abc",
    "bvrs": "721180.450460032",
    "bid": "ab.bc",
    "unique_vendor_identifier": "9982B084-BE66-4622-ACCB-6C5B3D9C4CD4",
    "web_order_line_item_id": "1000000037544589",
    "original_purchase_date_ms": "1516406580000",
    "expires_date_formatted": "2018-01-31 00:53:10 Etc/GMT",
    "purchase_date": "2018-01-31 00:23:10 Etc/GMT",
    "is_in_intro_offer_period": "false",
    "purchase_date_ms": "1517358190000",
    "expires_date_formatted_pst": "2018-01-30 16:53:10 America/Los_Angeles",
    "is_trial_period": "false",
    "purchase_date_pst": "2018-01-30 16:23:10 America/Los_Angeles",
    "original_purchase_date": "2018-01-20 00:03:00 Etc/GMT",
    "item_id": "1326212778"
  },
  "expiration_intent": "1",
  "is_in_billing_retry_period": "0"
}
```